# Create nested object on Entity Framework Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying fetch nested data from Ef query.

```
var imagePath = ImagePath.GetImagePath();
                   var data = repos.JobCategoryRepo.GetMany(x => x.Parent == null).Select(x => new JobCategoryModel
                    {
                        CategoryName = x.CategoryName,
                        Identifier = x.Identifier,
                        ImagePath = x.Images != null ? imagePath+"/"+x.Images.ImagePath : null,
                        ChildCategories =  x.SubCategory.Select(y => new JobCategoryModel
                        {
                            CategoryName = y.CategoryName,
                            Identifier = y.Identifier,
                            ImagePath = y.Images != null ? imagePath + "/" + y.Images.ImagePath : null,
                            ChildCategories=null
                        })
                    });
```

And     `repos.JobCategoryRepo.GetMany(x => x.Parent == null)` 
 will return IQueryable

As I know at second level, There is no ChildCategories, So At second level, I set `ChildCategories=null`

But Ef query doesn't allow me to assign Null value at this level.

> Unable to create a null constant value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[EntityModel.JobCategoryModel,
>   EntityModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
>   Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported
>   in this context.

And If remove `ChildCategories=null`
 then It will give error

> Internal exception has occured: The type
>   'EntityModel.JobCategoryModel' appears in two structurally
>   incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A
>   type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if
>   the same properties are set in both places and those properties are
>   set in the same order.

Comment: Just don't put it in the select, only assign `CategoryName` etc.

Comment: you mean to say, create anonymous object rather than creating `JobCategoryModel` object ?

Comment: No, fill in categoryname, identifier & imagepath but don't do anything with ChildCategories, then it won't give an error.

Comment: Does it help to use an empty array of type 'new JobCategoryModel[] { }' instead of the fix 'null' value? Or using the enumerable type  'Enumerable.Empty<JobCategoryModel>()'.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck : No , It won't work too. See my updated question.

Comment: @AmitKumar Didn't know it would throw an error because you use it twice in the query in a different way, I learn something new every day :) You'll have to use Tim's solution in that case

Comment: @TimEeckhaut : If assign an empty Enumerable, Then It give me 
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EntityModel.JobCategoryModel] Empty[JobCategoryModel]()' method`

Comment: @AmitKumar Use `new List<JobCategoryModel>()` instead

Comment: @TimEeckhaut: I already tried It, It give me same error as of previous

Comment: What is the type of `ChildCategories` member of your `JobCategoryModel`? e.g. `IEnumerable<JobCategoryModel>` or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second case (removing the `ChildCategories=null` assignment) sounds like a weird EF rule, I can't think of any logical reason for putting that constraint.

Anyway, the trick (workaround) is to define a fake derived class and project the inner select to it (with `ChildCategories=null` removed). So the following works:

```
class JobSubCategoryModel : JobCategoryModel { }

// ...
ChildCategories =  x.SubCategory.Select(y => new JobSubCategoryModel
{
    CategoryName = y.CategoryName,
    Identifier = y.Identifier,
    ImagePath = y.Images != null ? imagePath + "/" + y.Images.ImagePath : null,
})
```

Comment: I did the same trick. I worked. I created another class for childcategories .

Comment: I know because I've tried the solution before posting it :)